# Group by something that the database calculated

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the process of converting an old PHP application to a Rails one I stumbled across this piece of SQL code:

```sql
select week(datum)+1 as kw, year(datum) as jahr,
count(*) as anzahl,  
sum(dv) as dv 
from forecast
group by kw, jahr
order by jahr, kw;
```

The naming is in German:

- datum: date
- kw: calendar week
- jahr: year
- anzahl: count

I don't know and can't find in any documentation how to group by `kw` and `jahr` with ActiveRecord. It is possible to achieve this or do I have to use the SQL code?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to simply change the names from German to English instead of providing a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a model name like Forecast?
I think it is possible to do something like this:

```
Forecast.select(Arel.sql("week(datum)+1 as kw, year(datum) as jahr, count(*) as anzahl, sum(dv) as dv")).group(Arel.sql('kw, jahr')).order(Arel.sql('jahr, kw'))
```

Or you can use Arel to build the query.